# Migrate from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql

I have the following query written with Oracle

```
delete from EQUI_HIERARCHY; 

select max(level) into v_max_depth 
from EQUIP_D

connect by prior EQUIP_NO=PARENT_EQUIP_NO 
start with PARENT_EQUIP_NO is null;
```

How to transform it into SQL Server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SQL` standard way to implement recursive queries, as implemented e.g. by IBM DB2 and [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx), is the WITH clause. See [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0510rielau/) for one example of translating a CONNECT BY into a WITH (technically a recursive CTE) -- the example is for DB2 but I believe it will work on SQL Server as well.

In `SQL Server`, IBM DB2, or PostgreSQL 8.4 (as well as in the SQL standard, for what that's worth;-), the perfectly equivalent solution is instead a recursive query (more complex syntax, but, actually, even more power and flexibility):

```
    WITH n(v_max_depth ) AS 
         (SELECT max(level)
          FROM EQUIP_D
          WHERE PARENT_EQUIP_NO IS NULL
               UNION ALL
          SELECT max(level)
          FROM EQUIP_D as nplus1, n
          WHERE n.EQUIP_NO= nplus1.PARENT_EQUIP_NO)

   SELECT max(v_max_depth) FROM n
```

Oracle's `START WITH` clause becomes the first nested `SELECT`, the base case of the recursion, to be `UNIONed` with the recursive part which is just another `SELECT`.

SQL Server's specific flavor of WITH is of course documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28SQL.90%29.aspx), which also gives guidelines and limitations for using this keyword, as well as several examples.